# File Operations in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm working on a small application in Java that takes a directory structure and renames the files according to a certain format, after parsing the original name.

What is the best Java class / methodology to use in order to facilitate these file operations?

**Edit:** the question is only regarding the file operations part, I got the "getting the formatted name" down :)

**Edit 2:** Also, how do I list files recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.io.File`

---

**Listing all files in a directory**

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-code-snippets-tutorials/3-how-list-all-files-directory.html

```
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    // Do something with "listOfFiles[i]"
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

**To list the files recursively**, your best approach is fairly easy:

- Create a queue of directories. Initially add the first directory to the queue
- Pop the first directory element off the queue.
- List all files in that directory, same as above
- Iterate over all the files in that directory
- If a file is a directory (use `isDirectory()` method), add it to the back of the queue.
  Else, process this next file as needed (e.g. print)
- Stop when the queue is empty.

An example (I think a bit different from my approach above) is http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68

---

**Renaming a file**

http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/RenameFileOrDir.shtml

```
    boolean Rename = oldfile.renameTo(newfile);
```

---

**Finding a new name to rename to**

I'm not sure what you want the formatting rules to be - when I implemented the same utility in Perl for my own use I used Regular Expressions. For Java, that'd be [java.util.regex](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: Thanks! I found out how to do it recursively here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68

Comment: @Amir - LOL... I added the same link as an example. I think my algo above might be a bit more straightforward to implement (I saw a very novice Java developer do it in several minutes)

Answer (score 1):

This [Sun Totorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) could be a good start. If I where you I would basically retrieve all the files in the directory and then loop through them, as shown [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/). You might have to use regular expressions as well, a basic tutorial can be found [here](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the standard `java.io.File` class, but it's primitive and not very useful on its own.

For complex file-I/O operations, I recommend using [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), which provides a rich class library for (among other things) file operations. See classes like [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) and [FilesystemUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's the class [`File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), that does all you need:

- [listFiles()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)
- [renameTo()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)